# Ng-hide doesn't work when using <div> tags together

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to hide radio buttons using ng-hide functions. I am facing a strange problem.

When I use both ng-hide **supplierAdminLogs** and **BuyerAdminLogs** in div tags like shown in the html code below, both my radio buttons gets hidden instead of just one of them.

But when I remove one of the ng-hide in div tag, the other ng-hide div tag works perfectly by hiding the radio button. Thanks in advance.

```js
$scope.supplierAdminLogs = function() { // Hiding supplier/ buyer radio buttons on current user login role. 
  return true;
};
$scope.buyerAdminLogs = function() {
  return true;
};

$scope.adminRole = function() {

  var currentUser;
  if (localStorage.getItem("currentUser") !== null) {

    currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"));
    console.log("Received", currentUser);
  } else {
    console.log("Not received");
  }
  if (currentUser[0].role == "Supplier-Admin") {
    $scope.newUser.company = currentUser[0].company;

    $scope.supplierAdminLogs(); //CALLING THE FUNCTION HERE

    return false;
  } else if (currentUser[0].role == "Buyer-Admin") {
    $scope.newUser.company = currentUser[0].company;

    $scope.buyerAdminLogs(); //CALLING THE FUNCTION HERE

    return false;
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Role</label>

  <div>

    <div ng-hide="buyerAdminLogs()">
      <input type="radio" name="addRole" 
      ng-model="newUser.role" 
      ng-required="true" value="Supplier-Admin"> 
      Supplier-Admin <br />
    </div>

    <div ng-hide="supplierAdminLogs()">
      <input type="radio" name="addRole" 
      ng-model="newUser.role" 
      ng-required="true" value="Buyer-Admin"> 
      Buyer-Admin <br />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try with change value to ng-value

Comment: How do you mean? Please elaborate.

Comment: <input type="radio" name="addRole" 
      ng-model="newUser.role" 
      ng-required="true" ng-value="Buyer-Admin"> 
      Buyer-Admin <br />

Comment: the same with Supplier-Admin

Comment: Still the same issue :(.

Comment: Does your function $scope.buyerAdminLogs() call?

Comment: Yeah I debugged. It does get called.

Comment: If I remove the div-ng-hide in supplierAdmin or BuyerAdmin radio button, the other radio button works. There must be some clash between the two.

Comment: @BartoszTermena Never mind. I solved it. I moved the function of  supplierAdminLog and buyerAdminLog functions into the if statements in the adminRole function. It works now. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with checkbox validation like here:

```
  $scope.user = function(type){
    if(type === 'Supplier-Admin'){

       $scope.buyerAdminLogs = false;
    } else if (type === 'Buyer-Admin'){

       $scope.supplierAdminLogs = false;
    }
   console.log(type) 
  }
```

html:

```
 <div >
          <input type="checkbox" 
          ng-click="user('Supplier-Admin');supplierAdminLogs = true"
          ng-model="supplierAdminLogs"
          ng-required="true" ng-value="Supplier-Admin"> 
          Supplier-Admin <br />
        </div>

        <div >
          <input type="checkbox" 
          ng-click="user('Buyer-Admin');buyerAdminLogs = true"
          ng-model="buyerAdminLogs"
          ng-required="true" ng-value="Buyer-Admin"> 
          Buyer-Admin <br />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="buyerAdminLogs">buyerAdminLogs</div>
    <div ng-if="supplierAdminLogs">supplierAdminLogs</div>
```